# How can i get/copy/access the array that is in Rails from Angular

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

How can i get/copy/access the array that is in Rails from Angular? I have an array of strings, called `@array_of_names`, in my `def new` function and would like to have the same array (`@array_of_names`) in my Angular function. What's the way to do that so i could have @array_of_names in my Angular side?

**Rails file**

```
def new 
  @account = Account.new
  @array_of_names = read_names()
end
```

**Angular file**

```
(() => {

  angular
    .module('accounts')
    .controller('AccountsController', AccountsController)

  AccountsController.$inject = []

  //testing function
  function AccountsController () {
    let vm = this;
    vm.claim = "Hello, world!";
  }

})()
```

Comment: Use `$http` to make ajax request and have rails send json response

Comment: @charlietfl, I've only recently started rails and this is my first day of Angular experience.... could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: @charlietfl, could you please provide a simple example of how to that ? i'm still not getting into how http request is going to grab that array.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this via AJAX. You need to set up a route in the Rails app that returns a JSON object for Angular to use.

**Rails**

Replace *controller_name* with your controller name


Controller (/app/controllers/controller_name.rb):

```
def get_names
  render json: read_names()
end
```

Routes (/config/routes.rb):

```
get '/get_names' => 'controller_name#get_names'
```

**Angular**

```
function AccountsController($http){

  var vm = this;

  $http.get('/get_names').then(function(response){
    vm.names = response.data;
  });
}

AccountsController.$inject = ['$http'];
```

See this link to really understand what angular is doing: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Here is a link explaining how to work with Rails and more complex JSON responses
https://www.leighhalliday.com/responding-with-json-in-rails